# how to sort a multiple select field in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have a table question, the field "valeurs default" has the answers to all the questions which's gonna be a multiple selection field my problem is to add (Action box)  a small button to order the answers for  example for the question:  "age"
--> the answers will be displayed after clicking on the order button:
 " 20->25 25->30 30->35 "
[this is how it appears in my template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ij8cg.png)

can you help me please?

this is my entity "Question"

```
class Question
 {/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Libelle", type="string", length=150)
 */
private $libelle;
  /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="TypeQuestion", type="string", length=150)
 */
protected $TypeQuestion;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="tuto\BackofficeBundle\Entity\Service")
 */
protected $Service;

 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="tuto\BackofficeBundle\Entity\ValeursDefault")
 */
protected $ValeursDefault;
/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}
/**
 * Set libelle
 *
 * @param string $libelle
 *
 * @return Question
 */
public function setLibelle($libelle)
{
    $this->libelle = $libelle;
    return $this;
}
/**
 * Get libelle
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getLibelle()
{
    return $this->libelle;
}



/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->Service = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}


/**
 * Add Service
 *
 * @param \tuto\BackofficeBundle\Entity\Service $service
 * @return Question
 */
public function addService(\tuto\BackofficeBundle\Entity\Service $service)
{
    $this->Service[] = $service;
    return $this;
}
/**
 * Remove Service
 *
 * @param \tuto\BackofficeBundle\Entity\Service $service
 */
public function removeService(\tuto\BackofficeBundle\Entity\Service $service)
{
    $this->Service->removeElement($service);
}
/**
 * Get Service
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getService()
{
    return $this->Service;
}
/**
 * Add ValeursDefault
 *
 * @param \tuto\BackofficeBundle\Entity\ValeursDefault $valeursDefault
 * @return Question
 */
public function addValeursDefault(\tuto\BackofficeBundle\Entity\ValeursDefault $valeursDefault)
{
    $this->ValeursDefault[] = $valeursDefault;
    return $this;
}
/**
 * Remove ValeursDefault
 *
 * @param \tuto\BackofficeBundle\Entity\ValeursDefault $valeursDefault
 */
public function removeValeursDefault(\tuto\BackofficeBundle\Entity\ValeursDefault $valeursDefault)
{
    $this->ValeursDefault->removeElement($valeursDefault);
}
/**
 * Get ValeursDefault
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getValeursDefault()
{
    return $this->ValeursDefault;
}
/**
 * Set TypeQuestion
 *
 * @param string $typeQuestion
 * @return Question
 */
public function setTypeQuestion($typeQuestion)
{
    $this->TypeQuestion = $typeQuestion;
    return $this;
}
/**
 * Get TypeQuestion
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getTypeQuestion()
{
    return $this->TypeQuestion;
}
 }
```

[the html.twig file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PP7uF.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Write a twig extension that sorts ValeursDefault in twig.It's usually what I do with nested objects.

for more details http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

I had a similar problem before wanting to order child objects of an entity based on an attribute called position, so I wrote something like this

```
public function orderPosition($arr) {
    $size = count($arr);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
        for ($j = 0; $j < $size - 1 - $i; $j++) {
            if ($arr[$j + 1]->getPosition() < $arr[$j]->getPosition()) {
                $this->swap($arr, $j, $j + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

For your case, instead of getPosition() you'd be using whatever function you have in ValeursDefault that you want to sort by

Answer (score 1):

I think you can sort your values using Doctrine :

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/ordered-associations.html

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="tuto\BackofficeBundle\Entity\ValeursDefault")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"value" = "ASC"})
 */
protected $ValeursDefault;
```